# OpenOffice "Java framework" Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx)

Tags: linux, openoffice

I have a problem with my openoffice.org on a RedHad version of linux.

OpenOffice is successfully installed and from the command line if I run the following as root I get:

```
[root@s15548792 ~]# /usr/bin/ooffice "StarOffice.ServiceManager" -headless &
[1] 17321
[root@s15548792 ~]# ps | grep soffice.bin
17331 pts/0    00:00:00 soffice.bin
```

When I change the user apache I get this:

```
[root@s15548792 ~]# su apache
bash-3.2$ /usr/bin/ooffice "StarOffice.ServiceManager" -headless &
[1] 17341
bash-3.2$ [Java framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx).
javaldx failed!

[1]+  Done                    /usr/bin/ooffice "StarOffice.ServiceManager" -headless
bash-3.2$ ps -u `whoami` | grep soffice.bin
bash-3.2$
```

Its obviously a user issue but it looks to me like all of the OpenOffice.org files are owned by apache. I have searched for days now and the main solutions seems to be changing the owner of ~/.config to apache but I cant figure out how to do it.

If it helps when I run the comand using php I get the following output

```
[0] => Trying to open office... . /usr/bin/ooffice
[1] => [Java framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx).
[2] => javaldx failed!
[3] => creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
[4] => creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
[5] => creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
[6] => creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
[7] => creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
[8] => creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
[9] => timeout - office could not be started
```

Also the file /usr/bin/ooffice contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec openoffice.org "$@"
```

Any help would be much apreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I was having similar problem (with similar messages):

On our server nginx runs under user `www-data`. When we run OpenOffice (or any other applications we use), for security reasons we run it under user `www-apps` (user `www-data` is able to sudo to `www-apps`).

Unfortunately, I was getting this:

```
www-data@server:/tmp$ sudo -u www-apps /bin/bash
www-apps@server:/tmp$ oowriter -headless -nologo -norecovery -p report-8846.odt
[Java framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx).
javaldx failed! 
creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
```

The problem was that I needed to run the `sudo` command with `-H` argument to change the home directory from `/home/www-data` to `/home/www-apps`. Than it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You may have fixed this problem by now, but if not, find out the home directory for user apache by doing `cat /etc/passwd | grep apache` (the home directory will be the last but one field in the line).  Set this directory to be writable by user apache.  In my case, this fixed the problem (though I am not using apache, but am using lighttpd, in which case I had to do this to /var/www/ and set it to writable by www-data).

However, I am a novice at server management, and have no idea if this will make your web server insecure.